# After completing an AJAX query in a Datatable, how can I run another AJAX query for each data row passing the row data to it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, datatable

On loading a page using the `window.onload` function, I am sending an AJAX query to an endpoint using `jQuery.ajax`

If this AJAX query is successful, I am initializing a Datatable and rendering it with the data received from the query. Something like this:

```js
//Global variables
var jrow=0;
var rdata = new Array();
var table2;
var rinfo={};
var prow=0;

//AJAX success function
success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                for (var key in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        //Copying the data received array into rdata array
                        rdata[key] = data[key];
                    }
                }

                // Initializing the Datatable
                table2 =
                        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
                            "bProcessing": false,
                            "destroy": true,
                            "aaData": data,// <-- your array of objects
                            "sDefaultContent": "",
                            "aoColumns": [
                                {"mData": "text"},
                                {
                                    "mRender": function (data, type, full)
                                    {
                                    //Rendering unique div IDs for each row
                                        btn2 = '<div id="jiralink' + jrow + '"></div>'
                                        jrow++;
                                        return btn2;
                                    }
                                }
                    ]
                } );
            },
```

Now, once this Datatable is drawn after the AJAX query completes successfully, I want to run another background AJAX query to retrieve JIRA links for each row by passing that row data object and row index to a function.

The way I thought of achieving this was to define this function for the `complete` event of the AJAX query. So, something like this:

```js
 //AJAX Complete function
 complete: function(){
            //Since rdata is the array object of the entire datatable
            for (k in rdata) {
                 //row data object
                 rinfo = rdata[k];
          //So, for each row data, calling my function to retrieve JIRA Link
                 start_long_task(rinfo, prow)
                 prow = prow+1;
            }
            }
```

And, finally my `start_long_task` function looks something like this:

```js
function start_long_task(rinfo, prow) {

        div = $('<div class="jiralink' + prow+ '"><div></div><div>0%</div><div>&nbsp;</div></div><hr>');
        $('#jiralink' + prow).append(div);

       //Using nanobar to show the progress bar
        var nanobar = new Nanobar({
            bg: '#44f',
            target: document.getElementById('jiralink'+prow)
        });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/retrieveticket',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(rinfo),
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status, request) {
                    status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                    update_progress(status_url, nanobar, div[0]);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Unexpected error');
                }
            });
    }
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be working. I think initializing the row index value to 0 and then incrementing it is what is the problem. Is there any other way I should be approaching this?

Is there any other way such that after drawing the Datatable once, I can go over each row one by one in the background passing the row data and index to my `start_long_task` function so that the correct JIRA Link corresponding to that row is displayed in that row cell?

Comment: Have look at the datatable callback events, [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) and [drawCalback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head against this for quite some time, I have figured out how to make this work:

My createdRow function now looks like this:

```
"createdRow": function (row, data) {
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/retrievejiraticket',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status, request) {
                     status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                     sh(status_url, data, row)
                            }
                   });
            }
```

The `sh` function looks like this:

```
function sh(status_url, data, row){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: status_url,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json',
                context: row,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['state'] != 'PENDING' && data['state'] != 'PROGRESS') {
                        if ('issue_link' in data) {
                            issue_key = data['issue_key'];
                                $('#jiralink', this).html(issue_key);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Alert")
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        setTimeout(sh(status_url, data, row), my_delay);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
```

And, that's it.

As you can see, I am running an AJAX query (by calling function `sh`) inside another AJAX query (this gets called when the row first gets created in the Datatable via the function `createdRow`).

I am passing `status_url`, `data` and `row` to the `sh` function. `status_url` is the Celery Task Status URL that I periodically query to know the status of my job which gets submitted when the POST request is sent to the endpoint `/retrievejiraticket`. `data` is the data object with the response data in it from the Celery backend. `row` is the row object for the current row which I am using to set the `context` to `this`.

The trickiest part was to run the function `sh` recursively in a loop until the Celery tasks finished for each row (via the `setTimeout` function).

I wasn't able to do this if I called the 2nd AJAX query inside the first one itself without defining a function. I had to define a function (`sh`) and then define my 2nd AJAX query inside this function.

So, after the 1st AJAX query finishes, I use the success function and then call the `sh` function to execute my 2nd AJAX query inside that.

Thanks!! The above response definitely helped me think through this.